# Impossible to install the esp_camera library

Tags: esp32, library, ide, camera, esp32-cam

I cannot install the esp_camera library. When I try to add the .zip, I get "does not contain a valid library.

Everything about this ESP-32 Cam seems to rely on that library, and I can't find a way to install from https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera or any other way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "library" in the way that the Arduino system uses the term. That is, it's not designed to be placed under `<sketchbook>/libraries` directory way typical Arduino libraries are.

The good news is that you don't need to install it, because you already have it. It comes as part of the SDK files packaged into the ESP32 Arduino core as it is installed through the boards manager.

You'll find the header various places under the `<arduino15>/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/<version-number>/tools/sdk/esp32<architecture>/include/esp32-camera/driver/include/esp_camera.h` where arduino15 refers to [this](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360018448279-Open-the-Arduino15-folder), `version` refers to whatever version of the board package you have installed, and `architecture` is nothing, or `c2`, `s3`, or various other related esp32 suffixes.

The bulk of the code being in `<arduino15>/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/<version>/tools/sdk/esp32<architecture>/lib/libesp32-camera.a`

Comment: Thank you. It took a bit of time to grasp the difference between platforms when still using Arduino IDE.